# Firebase sms retriever limitations of sms frequency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I use [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) in my application.

When I use it the first time: at once I receive SMS on my phone, I receive and broadcast with SMS message (`com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED`).

When I use it again (in few seconds late): after I receive SMS takes about 30 seconds before I receive the broadcast.

Are there some limitations of SMS frequency in Google Play Services?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I did not notice any such thing. Could you Elaborate this?